# Reading historical Accelerometer data

Tags: ios, operating-system, apple-watch, watch

I have a requirement, where in i need to fetch last 2 to 3 days of accelerometer data. But for that you need to record data yourself using startRecording. But according to apple documentation you can record maximum if 12 hours of data. Now i am confused how to do that to achieve my target.

Maybe i am thinking for using background modes so that as soon as i get the backgroundSnapshot Task, i will again start to record data with startRecording.

If there is any other approach or if we can use same approach and if this may be reject by apple.

Please help soon.